# Exact same C++ Code works in Visual Studio but not in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, class, compiler-errors

This is an assignment for C++ class, it compiles and runs perfectly in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows, but I mainly code on OSX in Vim or Xcode.
XCode immediately shows me the error "no matching constructor for initialization of 'Vector'" in the line, same when I try to compile with a Makefile and the terminal.

```
    Vektor C = A + B; // !!! no matching constructor for initialization of 'Vector'
```

however,

```
    Vektor B = A;
    A + B;
```

work perfectly on both OSX and Windows.
I did not try to export/import project files, it's completely new files in every environment.

The complete code: http://pastebin.com/xabY0w08

Is that a known problem, if so, why does it happen and is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Did you forget to make the copy constructor argument `const`?

Comment: You spell `Vektor` with a **k** in the code but it's spelled with a **c** in the error?

Comment: And while doing so, check your prior **warning** log. VS should warn you when you're using a non-standard extension, and this is one of them. VS supports non-const references from rvalues; the standard does not.

Comment: Also note even with the change below you're only filling 2/3 of the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). you should also implement an assignment operator (and if so inclined,  a move-constructor and a move-assignment operator as well)

Answer (score 6):

Define the copy constructor as having const reference to an object of the class. For example

```
Vektor( const Vektor & );
```

Comment: +1 Or better still. make a proper *move constructor*, since the OP is using a C++11 (mostly) compliant toolchain on both platforms.

Comment: That doesn't immediatetely fix it, but I'll look into that and try to make the necessary constructors.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. You saved our bacon.

Comment: @Oliver Spryn  What do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

You must change:

```
Vektor(Vektor &quelle);
```

to

```
Vektor(const Vektor &quelle);
```

the reason is that temporary object `(A+B)` cannot bind to a non-const reference,

Answer (score 1):

in

```
Vektor C=A+B;
```

The `operator+` returns a `Vektor` - value, but your constructor accepts a `Vektor&` - reference.

You need to implements a contructor which receive a `const Vektor&` (just modify your existing one).

It works on windows because (not sure about that) Visual C++ is more lenient about const references.